# DseGraphFrames questions

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

following advices of smart people from datastax that answered some of my questions in stackoverflow, I've migrated to DSE 6.0.

The migration was thougher than expected but it finally worked.

Thanks to bug fixes in DSE 6, I can now launch DseGraphFrames.

The only problem is that there is not a lot of documentation around.

Where can I found some tutorials in how to mutate the graph with analytics jobs?

One example of what I want to do:

parse all the vertex of the graph with a particular label (let's say 'episode'), for each vertex calculate a counter based on the number of incident edges (let's say 'listenCounter'), and store this info in a property of the vertex ('listenCounter').

Any pointer where I can found information on how to do this? Of course after this simple, I would probably need to perform more complex jobs.

Thanks in advance!

Toufic Zayed

Comment: Do you need any additional information besides my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is long blog post "[Introducing DSE Graph Frames](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dse-graph-frame)" that has code examples. There is also [documentation bundled with DSE 6.0](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/dseGraphFrameOverview.html).

But basically, everything what you need is call to `updateVertices` & `updateEdges` on the Graph, passing the DataFrame that is formatted with `_id` & `~label` for Vertices, and `src`, `dst` & `~label` for Edges.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. There is also some videos on youtube that are insightful.